# Change SQLite default settings

Tags: sqlite

we know when type `.mode column` let me see tables like column 
And `.headers on` , we can see the header of tables.
But I want to know if there is any way make the two default settings?

Do some modify for the source code of sqlite??
OR is there a config file for these settings?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Put:

```
.headers on
.mode column
```

In a file called `.sqliterc` in the home directory of the user running sqlite.

(P.S. I found that in `man sqlite3`.)

Comment: If you are using Windows, you should create the file %USERPROFILE%\.sqliterc. For instance, by executing the following on the command-line: `(echo .mode columns && echo .headers on) >%USERPROFILE%\.sqliterc`

Comment: Create `.sqliterc` file if not avaialble in the home directory and add. Initially I thought `.sqliterc` is available in the home directory. But after reading man page again, I read this statement 'If the file ~/.sqliterc exists', if not avaialble, we can create it.

Comment: @chanduthedev yep, the ".something" file in home directory is a standard *nix way of doing user configuration, not obvious unless you're a *nix user

Comment: I was hoping there would be a global `.sqliterc` that applies to all users. But that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure using the following command to open the file:

```
nano ~/.sqliterc
```

then add

```
.headers on
.mode column
```

to the file and save it