# How can i set System.Data.SQLite to show header?

Tags: c#, sqlite

i can write and execute something like this with sqlite3 command (in command prompt):

```
sqlite3 -header sms.db "select * from message"
```

or i found changing default setting of sqlite in [Change SQLite default settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240643/change-sqlite-default-settings).

but i'm using c# and System.Data.SQLite.dll and then i haven't any of these solution... how can i set `headers on` ?

my c# code is like this:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path);

connection.Open();

SQLiteDataReader reader = new SQLiteCommand(connection) { CommandText = "select * from message" }.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    //...
}

reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "can't".  The headers cannot be turned on through any option in SQLite.

You can however retrieve the column names from the reader and display them yourself.

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path);

connection.Open();

SQLiteDataReader reader = new SQLiteCommand(connection) { CommandText = "select * from message" }.ExecuteReader();

bool needHeader = true;
while (reader.Read())
{
    // show header if this is the first row
    if(needHeader){
        ShowHeader(reader);
        needHeader = false;
    }
    //...
}

reader.Close();
connection.Close();

void ShowHeader(SQLiteDataReader reader){
    for (int i=0;i < reader.FieldCount;i++) 
    { 
      string fieldName = reader.GetName(i); 
      // use your display method here
      Console.Write(fieldName+"\t"); 
    }         
}
```