# Set default sqlite dot commands

Tags: sqlite

When I open the `sqlite3` command line in Windows Command Prompt, I each time type

```
.mode column
.width 8
.header on
```

Sometimes I choose a different width, but this is easy to change as needed.

Is there some way I can have these either as defaults, or execute each time the prompt starts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change SQLite default settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240643/change-sqlite-default-settings)

Answer (score 2):

The default rc file for SQLite is `~/.sqliterc`; see the man page. You just paste that lines there.

Answer (score 1):

Put these commands into a file, and give the file name to `sqlite3`'s `-init` option.

(The options are not in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html); see `sqlite3 --help` for a list.)